# How can I setup Visual Studio 2017 to properly recognize the Cuda code in the Optix project

Tags: c++, cuda, visual-studio-2017, optix

I try to get into the Optix projects and I have a problem with recognizing the Cuda code in the Visual Studio 2017.
I can build and execute the code (even the code in the .cu files), but variables and functions in .cu files, are marked as not recognized (are colored red). Is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: try googling "cuda red underline"

Answer (score -2):

Because the `cuda` program is compiled with `nvcc.exe` (it can be simply understood as c compilation). If the `.cp`p file contains the `.cu` file, the `.cu` file will be compiled with the c++ compiler. I suggest that you could add `extern "C"` in front of the functions which is called in the `.cu` file.